# dynamic generating broken seat

Tags: php

I am doing a fyp about bus travelling. Now the problem I encountered was, I am now using a trip table information to generate schedule every 12am. And my schedule table linked with seat table and bus table. So it make seat has `bus_id` and `schedule_id`. If I update a `seat_status` to broken. But my trip doesn't know the bus seat broken or not, except if I get the `seat_status` from previous schedule `seat_status`. So I wondering is it I having a problem with my database or my way looking at it.

Seat has seat_id, seat_row, seat_col, seat_status, bus_id, schedule_id. I will update seat_status to 0(available) 1(not available) 2(broken). But my trip was generated using query like

```
$row=array("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W",‌​"X","Y","Z"); 
for($i=0; $i<(get_TotalSeat($s["bus_id"])/4); $i++)
 { 
for($x=1; $x<=4; $x++) 
{ 
mysql_query("insert into seat(seat_row,seat_col,seat_status,bus_id,schedule_id)values('$row[$i]','$x','0'‌​,'$s[bus_id]','$s[s_id]')"); 
}
 }
```

I do not know how to get which bus which seat is broken, seat_status = 2, and insert the seat_status is 2 during generating

Comment: Please show the query you're running, examples of the data in your databases, eg, if you set the seat to broken, how you do that and so on.

Comment: It is indeed hard to understand your problem could you show a scheme of your database and try to further explain your problem?

Comment: Sounds like you need to model a) the bus, b) the *physical* seat, c) a bus schedule and d) how each seat relates to a bus schedule and/or specific times. Mushing the schedule into the seat is the wrong model.

Comment: Okay.. I think I get it.. I will try about the model.. Thank you. But could you teach or suggest me a correct way to do about the schedule and seat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a model along these lines:

```
table    buses
columns  id, name

table    seats
columns  id, bus_id, row, number, status

table    schedules
columns  id, bus_id, start_time, end_time, info

table    seats_schedules
columns  id, schedule_id, seat_id, status
```

You use the `seats_schedules` table to record the status of each seat during certain schedules.